# Discord Bot GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, discord.py, google-cloud-scheduler

I'd like to combine **GCP Cloud Scheduler** and **Cloud Functions** to send a message to a Discord Channel every week.

Ideally the Scheduler will use a HTTP trigger and the Cloud Function will then run, sending the message to the specific channel.

**main.py:**

```
import discord

def bot_function():
  client = discord.Client()
  channel_id = "CHANNEL_ID"
  @client.event
  async def on_ready():
      await client.get_channel(channel_id).send("TEST MESSAGE")
      
  client.run("API_KEY")
```

I've included discord in requirements.text, however, I'm getting the following errors when I test the function:
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URkqV.png):

1. *RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.,*
2. *RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread*
3. *TypeError: bot_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given*

Comment: You could use requests in python to send a HTTP request to discord's API to send the message instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better if you would consider webhooks with a schedule like this.

Get the webhook url from your server settings

[image]

```py
import requests #dependency

url = "<your url>" #webhook url, from here: https://i.imgur.com/aT3AThK.png

data = {}
#for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook
data["content"] = "message content"
data["username"] = "custom username"

#leave this out if you dont want an embed
data["embeds"] = []
embed = {}
#for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object
embed["description"] = "text in embed"
embed["title"] = "embed title"
data["embeds"].append(embed)

result = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

try:
    result.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
else:
    print(f"Payload delivered successfully, code {result.status_code}.")

#result: https://i.imgur.com/DRqXQzA.png
```